# Why is there a execution time difference between setimeout(function(), 0 ) and function()?

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout

I have a javascript animation code -

```
function animate(position)
{
    ....

    ....

    if(position++ < xyz){
        animate(position); // ****this is the line that I replace with in the next attempt.
    }


}
```

This takes around 1 seconds to execute . But if I put a timeout function with a 0 time , it takes around 15 seconds to complete .

```
setTimeout(function(){
            animate(position);
        }, 0);
```

Why does this huge time difference happen ? In the code I am trying to draw some pixels on an HTML5 canvas. I have omitted those codes to make my question clearer.

Comment: `func()` will execute the function immediately, while `setTimeout(func, 0)` will execute `func` after the current execution finished. If you are doing many other things, this could delay the execution of `func` (though 15 sec seems to be a bit much).

Comment: In my loop , there is nothing after the animate statement . So settimeout(0) should also mean execute immediately.

Comment: The whole animation is delayed by 15 seconds. The loop gets repeated around 1000 times . So 15 ms delay per loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning for this is in the way JavaScript handles timers internally. Since JavaScript is single threaded, nothing ever runs concurrently. Passing 0 milliseconds to `setTimeout` will just force the function to run at the first available moment.  John Resig has a nice write up on this at http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.

You can see this by running the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('one');
}, 0);
console.log('two');
```

`two` is logged before `one`.

I'm assuming you have a bunch of other things running and by queuing up `animate` you are making the execution wait until those other things complete.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout has some information on `setTimeout` clamping. See the "minimum delay" section.